Getting Energenie Pi-Mote IR control board to work on Raspbery Pi OS Bookworm
I've bought an Energenie Pi-Mote IR control board for controlling my TV from a raspberry pi 4b and I'm struggling to get it to work. The manufacturer supplied user guide (https://energenie4u.co.uk/res/pdfs/ENER314-IR_User_guide_V3.pdf) is very old and is pre-systemd, half the lirc files have changed locations, the module names have changed and who knows what else is different now.
I've found a couple of links which seem to be a bit more up to date about getting IR to work (though not specifically the Energenie module)...

Raspberry Pi 3 not lirc not running/working
https://gist.github.com/justinyoo/34e3470ced2641221c69ebeab6e034f7

But I can't seem to get it working correctly.
I decided to start with receiving IR signals from a remote control and be sure that was working before I worked my way up to blasting IR commands. Here's what I've done so far...

Connect the Energenie Pi-Mote IR control board to the Raspbery Pi GPIO so that pins 1 and 2 are at the GPIO pins furthest from the ethernet port (so it looks like the picture in the above linked user guide).

Make sure everything is up to date and install lirc...


apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install lirc


Modify  boot config
Add an extra line on the end of /boot/firmware/config.txt into the [all] section so that it looks like...

[all]
dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=18


Change /etc/lirc/lirc_options.conf


Change "driver" from "devinput" to "default"
Change "device" from "auto" to "/dev/lirc0"

So the top of the file looks like...
[lircd]
nodaemon        = False
driver          = default
device          = /dev/lirc0
output          = /var/run/lirc/lircd


Rebooted the raspberry pi

When it boots back up I can see /dev/lirc0 and lsmod lists gpio_ir_recv.
I then tried to test it by running...
sudo systemctl stop lircd.service lircd.socket
sudo mode2 --driver default --device /dev/lirc0

But before I can press any buttons on my remote control it non-stop prints out pulse and space lines like...
xxxx@pi:~ $ sudo mode2 --driver default --device /dev/lirc0
Using driver default on device /dev/lirc0
Trying device: /dev/lirc0
Using device: /dev/lirc0
Running as regular user xxxx
pulse 147
space 21927
pulse 49
space 782
pulse 109
timeout 130753
pulse 86
space 16884
pulse 89

Whilst I have a lot of kit in my office I don't believe I have anything that is chucking out tons of IR constantly, but just to be sure I have put the PI in a cardboard box, sealed it as much as possible and left the mode2 command running for a couple of minutes and it just never stops printing output.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

I’m voting to close this question because I feel it is un-answerable without more information; that information must come from you in the form of a clear explanation of what your 'IR Control board' is sending as output versus what it should be sending. Be reasonable - PLEASE - how do you expect people here to help you with a question about hardware & software that's this old with what you have supplied??

Hi, the hardware isn’t old, I bought it from CPC a week ago (https://cpc.farnell.com/energenie/ener314-ir/i-r-controller-board-for-raspberry/dp/SC13692) it’s the user guide that is old.
When I ran that mode2 command I was expecting no signal/pulse messages to be printed until I pressed a button on an IR remote, instead I got constant messages like there were hundreds of IR remotes in use.
I was hoping that someone else had one of these devices and had got it working on latest raspberry pi OS and could give me some pointers on where to look. If not I’ll email the manufacturer. Thanks

Hah!  :)  good luck... but maybe you should delete your question until you've got your new user guide?
